# How do I send a GET request while typing in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS.

I want to set it up so that as I type, I send a GET request, but only if what I've typed in the `input` field is at least three characters long.

Here's `index.html`:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="fetchTagsCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="userInput.fetchTag" placeholder="Type something">
</div>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('fetchTagsCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.userInput = {
        fetchTag: ''
    };

    $http({
        url: '/myURL',
        method: 'GET',
        param: {
            someParameter: $scope.userInput
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How do I fix this?

Comment: bind keyup event and fire the $http

Comment: @mohamedrias Where would I add the keyup event?

Comment: You need to bind it to your input text box. I've mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `keyup` event for that.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userInput.fetchTag" ng-keyup="fetchdata()" placeholder="Type something">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.fetchdata = function() {
  // condition to check for characters greater than 3.
  if($scope.userInput.fetchTag.length < 4) return;
  $http({
        url: '/myURL',
        method: 'GET',
        params : {
            someParameter: $scope.userInput
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Also inject `$http` in your controller.

Comment: inject that in your controller.

Comment: `app.controller('fetchTagsCtrl',function($scope, $http){`

Comment: d'oh, I forgot to add `$http`. Ok, this code almost works. Just change `param` to `params`, which is a typo I made, too

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, i've updated my answer based on comments.

Answer (score 4):

Your html dom was right. Just simply change would be on your script. Follow the step which provided below

**Step 1:**
Inject $http to your controller
 Ex: app.controller('fetchTagsCtrl',function($scope,$http)

**Step 2:**
Use $scope.$watch to get your typing event from your input

Let's look at the code below will be look like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('fetchTagsCtrl',function($scope,$http){
$scope.userInput = {
    fetchTag: ''
};
$scope.$watch('userInput.fetchTag',function(){
    $http({
        url: '/myURL',
        method: 'GET',
        param: {
            someParameter: $scope.userInput
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
     })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-change directive instead of ng-keyup .because for every change in input it calls to the fetchdata method in controller.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userInput.fetchTag" ng-change="fetchdata(userInput.fetchTag)" placeholder="Type something">

$scope.fetchdata = function() {
  // condition to check for characters greater than 3.
  if($scope.userInput.fetchTag.length > 3) 
  $http({
        url: '/myURL',
        method: 'GET',
        params : {
            someParameter: $scope.userInput
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch the model for changes, do a check, then fire your request.  Here's how I'd write it:

```
app.controller('fetchTagsCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.userInput = {
        fetchTag: ''
    };;

    $scope.$watch('userInput.fetchTag',function(value){
        if(value.length >= 3){
            makeRequest();
        }
    });

    function makeRequest(){
        $http({
            url: '/myURL',
            method: 'GET',
            param: {
                someParameter: $scope.userInput.fetchTag
            }
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: `$scope.$watch` is great for listening to changes in data. But even if someother model in that controller changes, this `watch` will execute in the `$digest` cycle. So i feel keyup event / oninput event would be good for this.